# Proofs involving endomorphisms on the space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Define endomorphisms $D$ and $E$ on the space of polynomials with rational co-efficients $ \mathbb{Q}[x] $ such that $ D(x^n)= nx^{n-1}, E(x^n) = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} $

We must show that $ DE = I $ but $ ED \neq I $

I attempted to write as a composition or as 2 matrices but got nowhere . Any ideas?

I also need to show that given $ f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $, show that $ D^n f(x) = 0 $, for some $ n \geq 1 $

I really have no idea how to approach this, possibly because I haven't got part (i).

And finally given  $ n \geq 1 $, show $ D^n \neq 0 $. If someone could show me the method of answering this problem, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

If someone could show me the method of answering these questions that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Since the dimension is (countably) infinite, these endomorphism cannot be given by any (finite) matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two endomorphisms are equal if and only if they act the same on all elements of a basis. Now
$$
DE(x^n)=D\left(\frac{1}{n+1}x^n\right)=x^n
$$
so indeed $DE=I$. However,
$$
ED(x^n)=E(nx^{n-1})=x^n
$$
if and only if $n>0$. Indeed, $ED(1)=E(0)=0\ne1$.

Next, prove by induction that $D^n\ne0$.

The base step is clear, because $D(x)=1$. Suppose $D^n\ne0$. Then take $f$ with $D^n(f)\ne0$. So $D^{n+1}(E(f))=D^nDE(f)=D^n(f)\ne0$. So $D^{n+1}\ne0$ as well.

Comment: Concise, to the point, complete. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

So the best way to see that $ED\neq I$ is to show that it is not injective, or that it has a nontrivial kernel.

Note: let $f(x) = 1$ be the constant polynomial. Then $D(f(x)) = 0$ (this should be part of the definition of $D$), so $ED(f(x)) = 0 \neq f(x)$. Thus, $ED\neq  I$.

In terms of your other questions, pursue this same thought :

$D(c) = 0$ for $c\in \mathbb Q$. This will let you see that for each $f(x)$ there is some $n>0$ such that $D^n(f(x))=0$.

Yet for each $n>0$, what is $D^n(x^{n+1})$?